# BlackBerry: Are there any examples on how to localize BB apps for right-to-left languages like Arabic, Hebrew?

Tags: blackberry, localization, arabic, right-to-left

I want to localize my Blackberry app to use Arabic language which is right-to-left. I am using SDK 4.5 because I want my app to be forward compatible. I read in [this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17965/BP_Coding_for_different_languages_regions_6_0_1178371_11.jsp) article guidelines for rtl localization. However, none of their suggestions worked (FIELD_LEADING, USE_ALL_WIDTH and isLeftToRight). What should I do exactly to make my fields (Labels and ObjectChoiceFields) align correctly to the right of screen? Are there examples?

Answer (score 1):

These are features of the 6.0 OS, so they won't work on 4.5.  Yes, they really are that far behind.